# Downloading files from google cloud storage and search good documantation by apies for php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I began to work with Google Cloud Storage

I am currently using the library [Google API PHP Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

The documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples) however I couldn't find any php documentation related to the APIs of the library.

And I've problem with downloading files from storage. I know how upload, but I don't know how download.

```
$res = $storage->objects->insert(
        "bucket",
        $obj,
        ['name' => $file_name, 'data' => file_get_contents('path'), 'uploadType' => 'multipart', 'mimeType'=>'text/xml']
    );
```

I can get data of file, but I can't download.

```
$res = $storage->objects->get(
        "bucket",
        $file_name,
        []
    );
```

Thanks

Comment: You can find documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/overview?hl=en_US) and explore apis [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/storage/v1/).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I saw this documentation before, and it not clear describe enough. How I can download file from storage, I used storage.objects.get, and I got link to image in parameter "mediaLink". file_get_contents doesn't have access by this link to file, maybe I missed something

Answer (score 1):

$storage->objects->get

This api returns mediaLink parameter and by this link we can download from storage